# “I capitalised this letter”

Tags: word-choice

How do you say, “I capitalised this letter”?

How would a native English speaker phrase the following sentences?

1. i wrote it with a lower case letter
2. i wrote it with a capital letter
3. i have replaced upper case letter on lower case letter.

By “letter”, I do not mean a letter (e.g. mail), I mean the characters used to make words.

Comment: For the record, I disagree with the reasons this question was closed. I'm glad it got a few answers first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I wrote it with a lowercase letter.

2) I wrote it with a capital letter.

3) I replaced the uppercase letter with a lowercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on exactly how something is actually written, I would lean toward:

> - I wrote it in lowercase.  (*"thing"*)
> - I wrote it in uppercase. -or- I wrote it in all-caps.  (*"THING"*)
> - I capitalized it.  (*writing "Thing", or converting "thing" -> "Thing"*)
> - I lowercased it. *-or-* I un-capitalized it.  (*converting "Thing" or "THING" -> "thing"*)
> - I uppercased it.  (*converting "thing" -> "THING"*)

Answer (score 0):

1) I wrote it with a lowercase letter.

2) I wrote it with a capital letter.

3) I have replaced an/the uppercase letter with a/the lowercase letter.